# Hide items in Sharepoint Treeview

Tags: 2010, navigation, hidden

Any idea to hide non-site items in the Sharepoint 2010 tree view control?
Or the only chance is to develop our own control and integrate it on the master page?

there's this [link](http://piroozjavan.blogspot.com/2011/01/customizing-sharepoint-2010-tree-view.html) but it doesn't seems so quite simple.

ideas?

**Updated:** *Actually it works fine in masterpages, but only in blank sites. anyone knows why?*

Comment: what exactly do you want to display/hide.. the article looks simple enough.

Comment: hide all site content in tree view control, leaving only the inherent Sites and Subsites below it.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just show Sites and Subsites below it, you can setup the Data Source like this:

```
 <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl runat="server" ID="TreeViewDataSource"  
        IncludeDiscussionFolders="false" ShowListChildren="false" ShowDocLibChildren="false"
        ShowFolderChildren="false" RootContextObject="Web" />
```

And use above data source with the treeview as shown below:

```
  <SharePoint:SPTreeView runat="server" ID="WebTreeView" ShowLines="false" DataSourceID="TreeViewDataSource"
        ExpandDepth="0" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-navitem"
        NodeStyle-HorizontalPadding="2" SkipLinkText="" NodeIndent="12" ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/MDNCollapsed.png"
        ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/images/tvclosedrtl.png" CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/images/MDNExpanded.png"
        CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/images/tvopenrtl.png" NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvblank.gif"
        AutoExpandSelectedNode="true">

    </SharePoint:SPTreeView>
```

I tested above in custom application page and it apperas as below:

[image]

Comment: It works, for real. thanks.
But actually I was trying to get the same result throw the masterpage and that is what I'm not getting to.