# Hide some lists from treeview?

Tags: 2010

I want to use the tree view on the left side, but I don't want it so show some of the document libraries such as Site Assets and Style Library - they need to be on the site, but users don't need to see them.

Is there any way to control what shows up in the tree view?

This is similar to [Hide items in Sharepoint Treeview](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27828/hide-items-in-sharepoint-treeview) but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into Sharepoint Designer and select your list(s). Tick the check box for Hide From Browser. This will remove it from all aspects of the UI, including the tree view.

[image]

Comment: This will remove it from the Treeview as well as "site content" :(

Comment: That's what I said, it hides it from all aspects of the UI.

Comment: Another drawback of this, hidden libraries will also not appear in search result

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom data provider for the treeview control and then use something like the additionalpagehead delegate control to instantiate it and set it as the datasource for the treeview.

Here is an example of creating a custom site map provider: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96461/Building-a-Custom-Site-Map-Provider

Here is an example of using the additionalpagehead control: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/

And all you'd need to do with the TreeView control itself is:

```
WebTreeView.DataSourceID = null;
WebTreeView.DataSource = yourcustomsource;
WebTreeView.DataBind();
```

Comment: John, please don't post duplicate answers - better to flag the questions as duplicates. I have closed the other question as a duplicate so we're all good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initial answer on SharePoint designer checkbox is very helpful.  To the comment about the feature hiding the element from "Site Content" as well - there is an easy work-around for that.  Just build a Site Admin Link List and make sure to create links for all hidden elements before hiding them.  Then set security on link list to just the people who need access to the hidden elements.  This provides way for site admins to get to the hidden elements when needed but allows you to follow instructions in this topic for hiding it from tree-view and navigation.

Note too - it is only hidden when you are on a standard site page.  From LSB, click the "Libraries" link or "Lists" link and when you jump to that page and scroll to bottom you should see the "Site Content" link re-appear in that context. (at least it did for me).  I believe we are using SharePoint 2010.

Untested:  I also suspect you can add a link on navigation for the site (to appear in global heading, or LSB) if you need to and this could allow you to link to a desired feature in navigation while hiding it from treeview (but i haven't tested this idea yet).