# Sharepoint 2013 Quick Launch Treeview

Tags: 2013, quick-launch

is it possible to change the order of the menu in the Quick Launch in treeview mode only ?

Thanks you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms466994(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: thanks you but I can't see how can I change the order in my treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your post, my understanding is that you want to reorder the `Tree View of the site contents in SharePoint 2013`.

Per my knowledge, we only can `enable or disable` the Tree View in the `Site Settings`, there is **no out of box way to reorder the Tree View in SharePoint** as DareDevil say.

As a workaround, if you simply want to hide some lists which is not necessary from the Tree View, I recommend that you can select the **Hide from browser** check box in the **General Settings** of these lists by using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Also, you can try to add some proper prefix on the names of the site contents to regularly reorder the Tree View based on your need.

And, if you still want to implement the customizable order of the Tree View, you need to customize own code to create a new Tree View to get the site contents dynamically and add it into the master page to replace the default Tree View.

**There are some articles as below for your reference:**

- [Overview of site navigation in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee695757(v=office.15).aspx)
- http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59774/hide-some-lists-from-treeview
- [Site Map Web Part (SharePoint 2013)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775248/Site-Map-Web-Part-SharePoint)

Comment: thanks you sathish. To resolved my problem, it's mandatory to create my treeview.